# Calling a code when the onbeforeunload is called

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp. In that jsp i load other jsps in a div.
I want to run a code when the user closes the browser.
I came to know that onbeforeunload should be called in the javascript.
But whenever the page inside the div changes the onbeforeunload is getting called.
I just want to call onbeforeunload when the user exits the browser. 
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: show us the code in which the issue occurs

Comment: there are numerous posts on this topic....majority of which have same recommendation...don't rely on `onbeforeunload` to do much. It is not a reliable event to run any sensitive code with

Comment: @charlietfl : Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @Bonakid : sorry. Just imagine a jsp with a div and we load pages in that div. Cant post the code here.

Comment: to do what? If you are trying to send data to server...shouldn't try to check for user leaving (absence), rather should track user existence and use interval to ping server while user is on page.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` wont work in opera ...

Comment: @charlietfl : When the user closes the browser i want to edit the system properties on a servlet.
But only when he tries closing the browser and not when he changes the page.
Is there any way to call the script when the user tries closing the browser.
My approach was to submit a form to servlet and call the code onbeforeunload. But that doesnt seem to work and its getting called when the page gets refreshed. Infact its not going to the servlet at all.

Comment: no...it's too late...user can leave page too fast and it can be closing browser, clicking link, back button, refresh etc....give up the whole idea. Also think about powerfail and cross browser problems as well. Read the other posts. Update your settings as they are changed by user